# Did I press tofu enough? Or is there another problem? Created tofu spread

Tags: tofu

Hello I was making tofu for the first time starting with dried soy beans. I was following this youtube tutorial: https://youtu.be/IdGwL5dFgCQ

I used lemon juice diluted with water as my coagulant. The end result after pressing with 10 lbs or 5 kg worth of weight for 3 hours is below:

Is the reason the tofu did not firm up because I didn't press enough or could there have been another issue?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would try again with gypsum (calcium sulfate) or nigari as your coagulant. The result will be more consistent and of higher quality. Lemon and other acids are less common coagulants.

Comment: I'll try and update the post.

Comment: Yep just tried again this time with nigari and it worked like a charm. Thanks for the help!